# Elasticsearch nested search

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my mapping:

```
def searchkick_index
{
  settings: {
    # Custom settings if needed
  },
  mappings: {
    properties: {
      inventoryindex: { type: 'keyword' },
      codebook3index: { type: 'keyword' },
      warehouseindex: { type: 'keyword' },
      rackno: { type: 'keyword' },
      qty: { type: 'integer' },
      unitsize: { type: 'integer' },
      secno: { type: 'keyword' },
      deleteflag: { type: 'boolean' },
      productindex: { type: 'keyword' },
      fullunit: { type: 'keyword' },
      site: { type: 'keyword' },
      lab_hold: { type: 'boolean' },
      arrivaldate: { type: 'date' },
      qccleared: { type: 'boolean' },
      lotno: { type: 'keyword' },
      recordtime: { type: 'date' },
      rcvdunitsize: { type: 'integer' },
      product: {
        type: 'nested',
        properties: {
          productindex: { type: 'keyword' },
          productcode: { type: 'keyword' },
          productdesc: { type: 'text' }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
end
```

And here is my query and it works fine:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "deleteflag": false } },
        { "match": { "lotno": "123003001*" } }
      ]
    }
  }
```

But if I want to filter by `product.prodoctcode` as below, the results is empty and I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "deleteflag": false } },
        { "match": { "lotno": "123003001*" } },
        { "match": { "product.productcode": "20381ONPW" } }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I used Searchkick `gem` in Ruby on Rails application and my mapping in the model as below:

```
def search_data
    {
      inventoryindex: inventoryindex,
      codebook3index: codebook3index,
      warehouseindex: warehouseindex,
      rackno: rackno,
      qty: qty,
      unitsize: unitsize,
      secno: secno,
      deleteflag: deleteflag,
      productindex: productindex,
      fullunit: fullunit,
      site: site,
      lab_hold: lab_hold,
      arrivaldate: arrivaldate,
      qccleared: qccleared,
      lotno: lotno,
      recordtime: recordtime,
      rcvdunitsize: rcvdunitsize,
      product: [
        {
          productindex: product.productindex,
          productcode: product.productcode,
          productdesc: product.productdesc
        }
      ]
    }
  end
```

Comment: please add mapping, here you added no mapping, just document example

Comment: @ЕгорЛебедев I have edited my question

Answer (score 2):

The nested field are indexed as separate hidden documents, so they require a special queries to search. There are three possible solutions here.

1. You can index nested fields not only as hidden document but also as part of the parent document. To do that set `include_in_parent` or `include_in_root` in the nested field mapping. In this case your search will work as is, but you will index this field essentially twice.
2. You can leave mapping as is and use the special [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) instead of the last `match`:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "deleteflag": false } },
        { "match": { "lotno": "123003001*" } },
        { 
          "nested": {
            "path": "product",
            "query": {
              "match": { "product.productcode": "20381ONPW" }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

3. If you are not planning to ever search by product code, index and description at the same time (for example, find all records where at least one product has both index "ABC" AND description "XYZ") you can convert products from nested to objects. Please, make sure you fully understand the limitations of this solution comparing to nested before proceeding.

Comment: I am not going filter those three fields(lotno, productcode, productdesc) at the same time and could you please guide me how to convert nested to objects? thank you. the second solution not working.

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Can you post a mapping for the index from elasticsearch so I can reproduce your situation without converting it from whatever language you are using into JSON? Conversions to object is as easy as replacing word "nested" in mapping with the word "object".

Comment: I removed the nested part and now its working fine `"bool": {
            "must": [
              { "match": { "deleteflag": false } },
              { "wildcard": { "lotno": "#{params[:lot_no]}*" }},
              { "wildcard": { "product.productcode": "#{params[:productcode]}*" } }
            ]
          }`